# How to use math expression in mysql sql?

Tags: mysql

See below.
If use like this:

> select product_id, name from product limit **(1-1)*5**, 5;
>   ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(1-1)*5, 5' at line 1

but if use like this:

> select (1-1)*5 ;
>   +---------+
>   | (1-1)*5 |
>   +---------+
>   |       0 |
>   +---------+
>   It's ok.

How to use math expression in first statement？

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html: _“`LIMIT` takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative **integer constants**.”_ And it goes on to list two exceptions, placeholders in prepared statements, and parameters or variables in a stored procedure (the latter only from 5.5.6 on). So looks like other than that, you can use only integers there, and not expressions.

Comment: @CBroe put that in answer form so we can upvote.

Comment: Why would you need to do that in the first place? It looks like you are working on some pagination functionality, so why wouldn't you just calculate the page number in your application logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html says,

> `LIMIT` takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative **integer constants**.

And it goes on to list two exceptions,

- placeholders in prepared statements, and
- parameters or variables in a stored procedure (the latter only from 5.5.6 on).

So looks like other than that, you can use only integers there, and not expressions.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that if want to support this funtion, you have to modify mysql source code.